# Converting MySQL date field to strings

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

In my app I am using JSON to retrieve MySQL records.

One of the fields is from date type ( 2014-03-08 ), and I want to show it on a tableView cell but converted to four strings:

1. Day of the week (e.g. Monday).
2. Month (e.g. March).
3. Year (e.g. 2014).
4. Time (e.g. 11:00).

The MySQL fields are:

1. 2014-03-10
2. 2014-03-25
3. 2014-12-01

I am using the following code to do what I need:

```
  NSString *fecha = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"dia"];//fecha is the date from MySQL.


    //convertir fecha


    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yy-mm-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:fecha];



    NSDateFormatter *weekDay = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [weekDay setDateFormat:@"EEEE"]; //day of the week

    NSDateFormatter *calMonth =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [calMonth setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];//month in text format(March)

    NSDateFormatter *calYear = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [calYear setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];//year

    NSDateFormatter *calDay = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [calDay setDateFormat:@"dd"]; //day

    cell.diaLabel.text = [calDay stringFromDate:date] ;//label to show day


    cell.diaSemanaLabel.text = [weekDay stringFromDate:date];//label to show weekDay 

    cell.mesLabel.text = [calMonth stringFromDate:date];//label to show month

    cell.anoLabel.text = [calYear stringFromDate:date];//label to show year

    NSString *hora = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"hora"];//hora  is the time field from MySQL

    cell.horaLabel.text = hora; //label to show the time
    //fin convertir fecha
```

All strings are shown perfectly, except the month string, it always shows 'January'.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formatter string for parsing the date should be `@"yyyy-MM-dd"`, not `@"yy-mm-dd"`. The `MM` is for month. The `mm` is for minute. If you log the `NSDate` value (or examine it in the debugger), you can confirm that your current format string is not retrieving the date you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSString *fecha = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"dia"];//fecha is the date from MySQL.


    //convertir fecha


    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:fecha];



    NSDateFormatter *weekDay = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [weekDay setDateFormat:@"EEEE"]; //day of the week

    NSDateFormatter *calMonth =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [calMonth setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];//month in text format(March)

    NSDateFormatter *calYear = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [calYear setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];//year

    NSDateFormatter *calDay = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [calDay setDateFormat:@"dd"]; //day

    cell.diaLabel.text = [calDay stringFromDate:date] ;//label to show day


    cell.diaSemanaLabel.text = [weekDay stringFromDate:date];//label to show weekDay 

    cell.mesLabel.text = [calMonth stringFromDate:date];//label to show month

    cell.anoLabel.text = [calYear stringFromDate:date];//label to show year

    NSString *hora = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"hora"];//hora  is the time field from MySQL

    cell.horaLabel.text = hora; //label to show the time
    //fin convertir fecha
```